# Java: Cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)

Tags: java, json, rest, api, service

I'm a QA with desire to learn more about Java programming and problem I'm experiencing is this: 
I'm trying to POST Employee data to the database of some fake Rest API, but I'm getting

> Cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call
>   setDoOutput(true)"

So far, I tried some ideas from StackOverflow, but inexperienced as I am, I could easily fall deeper into a problem. 
So URL is: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create and firstly I created an Employee class of json object:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();   
    }

    public Main() {    

        Employees em = new Employees();

        em.setEmployeeName("Alex");
        em.setEmployeeSalary("1234");
        em.setEmployeeAge("28");

        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");  

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unsuccessful call: HTTP error : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
            }     

            // URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            // urlc.setDoOutput(true);

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());


            pw.print(new Gson().toJson(em));
            pw.close();
            pw.flush();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())
            );
            String json = "";
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                json += output;
            }
            conn.disconnect();               

            System.out.println("Employee name:  " + em.getEmployeeName());
        }   
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    }
}
```

Well, using one of your ideas and added next lines of code (it's commented in above code):

```
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
urlc.setDoOutput(true);
```

So the code looks like:

> public class Main {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
> new Main();   
> }
> public Main() {    
>
>     Employees em = new Employees();
>
>     em.setEmployeeName("Alex");
>     em.setEmployeeSalary("1234");
>     em.setEmployeeAge("28");
>
>     try{
>         URL url = new URL("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create");
>         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
>         conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");  
>
>
>
>         if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
>         throw new RuntimeException("Unsuccessful call: HTTP error : "
>         + conn.getResponseCode());
>        }     
>
>         URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
>        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
>
>         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(urlc.getOutputStream());
>
>
>         pw.print(new Gson().toJson(em));
>         pw.close();
>         pw.flush();
>
>         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>         (urlc.getInputStream())));
>         String json = "";
>         String output;
>         while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
>         json += output;
>         }
>         conn.disconnect();         
>
>
>
>         System.out.println("Employee name: " + em.getEmployeeName());
>
> }   
> catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
>     e.printStackTrace(); } 
>     catch (IOException e) { 
>     e.printStackTrace();        
> }
>  }}
> ```

With this second code I'm not getting that error, but there is no inserting to the database(checking that using postman, with GET method)...

Well, what am I missing? I guess, I'm missing something basic...

Comment: Forgot to add - With this second code I'm not getting that error, but there is no inserting to the database(checking that using postman, with  GET method)...

Comment: If you're going to be posting Java here, you'd be well advised to learn proper indentation. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I thought I've posted properly

Comment: Log the `json` string that you're reading from the response. You'll see the error there. The test API you linked is documented to take a string of the form `{"name":"test","salary":"123","age":"23"}`. I suspect that your gson serialised `Employees` object isn't in the form expected by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using url.openConnection twice means you get two different connections. You send the request to the second connection, and try to read the response from the first connection. You should call doOutput on the connection you open originally.

The second problem is you're calling getResponseCode before the request is sent. In http, the request must be sent entirely before the server sends a response. You should move the code that calls doOutput and writes the request body before the code that tries to check the response code.